# Oracle database 21c Express editon: startup ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle21c

Oracle database 21c Express editon: startup ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

[image]

```sql
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jan 11 14:07:51 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Wed Jan 11 2023 10:30:00 +07:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> startup;
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
SQL>
```

Why use user `system` but still not inssufficient privileges?

Comment: Try to connect using  `sys as sysdba`, provide password, and then run `startup`

Comment: It works! You can post your answer, I will accept it. What is the list of users can run as sysdba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect using `sys as sysdba`, provide password, and then run `startup`.

---

List of users who were granted the `sysdba` privilege is in `v$pwfile_users`:

```
SQL> select * from v$pwfile_users;

USERNAME                       SYSDBA     SYSOPER    SYSASM
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
SYS                            TRUE       TRUE       FALSE

SQL>
```